# Check if PDF file is created correctly

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, corrupt

I have code that generates a PDF then emails this file. Occasionally the file gets 'corrupted' but it can still be opened it just shows strange characters:

[image]

The PDF file still opens so there is no way of knowing there is a problem with the file until you open and see it. Is there anyway of checking that the PDF file didn't get created as it should have? Or check for these strange characters in the file?

Currently using using open-source tool wkhtml2pdf to convert Html page at a given URL to a PDF file. Link to tool: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

```
var pdfUrl = PdfGenerator.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdf("/App_Data/",
outputFilenamePrefix: "GeneratedPDF",
urls: new string[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMAILLINK"].ToString() + "Printouts/Invoice.aspx" },
FileName: invNoCheck.ToString() + ".pdf");
```

Comment: This looks like mixed up ASCII text, not corrupted text. If you can open it, it's *not* corrupted.

Comment: How can it "occasionally get corrupted" in the first place?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok maybe corrupted was the wrong word to use, but the pdf file didn't generate as it should have. Is there a way to check for this ASCII text?

Comment: Where does this data come from? A database query? A file? Most likely the source data was read with the wrong codepage. PS posting *invoice data* to a random URL is probably *not* legal - do you have *any* idea what that service does with that *sensitive* data?

Comment: @user123456789 post your *actual* code. It's probably *your* code that reads non-English text the wrong way. We can't guess what that code does - but I'm pretty sure whatever it is, it's not legal

Comment: @FCin unfortunately it is hard to replicate this issue. We create 1000s of PDF files each day but a few times a month a file will generate with these characters. Which is why I'm trying to find code to check for this

Comment: Two things come to mind: 1) the source HTML page doesn't specify a character encoding and the wkhtmltopdf tool can't figure it out, or 2) you could be corrupting the PDF when you download the response from pdfUrl.

Comment: What was this string supposed to look like? It could be UTF8, it could be some other codepage, but we can't just guess from looking at the replacement characters

Comment: @AlwaysLearning is there a way to check for these characters? Like I said in the question the wkhtmltopdf tool still creates the PDF file and it looks like everything is fine until you actually open the file and see those characters

Comment: @user123456789 you don't have to check for those characters, you have to fix the code that mangles them before sending them to the service. Post the code that loads the data and what this string is supposed to look like.

Comment: @user123456789 if AlwaysLearning's suspicion is correct, you only need to add an encoding attribute to the HTML page, and ensure it's saved as UTF8.

Comment: You probably won't find those characters because they're the result of mangling. For option 1): assuming "blahblahblah.../Printouts/Invoice.aspx" is a page you actually control, does it output a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=<someCharset>` response header or `<meta charset="<someCharset>">` the HTML head section? Where someCharset matches whatever your database's charset/collation is.